# Roslyn: generate method optional parameters from reflected interface

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, option-type, roslyn

Given `SomeInterfaceType` that has a method with optional parameters:

```
interface SomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod(int a = 1, string c = "foo",
                    SomeType e = default, SomeType f = null);
}

SomeInterfaceType = typeof(SomeInterface);
```

How do I create a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` from the reflected type?

I'm retrieving the list of parameters from the `MethodInfo` like this:

```
private ParameterListSyntax GenerateParameterListSyntax(MethodInfo info)
{ 
    var parameters = info.GetParameters();
    var parameterList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<ParameterSyntax>();

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        var parameterSyntax = SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(parameter.Name))
                    .WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(TypeNameOrAlias(parameter.ParameterType)));

        if (parameter.IsOptional)
        {
            parameterSyntax = parameterSyntax.WithDefault( <<< WHAT DO I DO HERE?>>> );
        }

        parameterList.Add(parameterSyntax);
    }

    return SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(parameterList);
}
```

How do I autogenerate the `EqualsValueClause` to complete the `WithDefault` method ?

I leave here the output of [RoslynQuoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) for `SomeInterface` as reference.

```
CompilationUnit()
.WithMembers(
    SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
        InterfaceDeclaration("SomeInterface")
        .WithMembers(
            SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                MethodDeclaration(
                    PredefinedType(
                        Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword)),
                    Identifier("SomeMethod"))
                .WithParameterList(
                    ParameterList(
                        SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(
                            new SyntaxNodeOrToken[]{
                                Parameter(
                                    Identifier("a"))
                                .WithType(
                                    PredefinedType(
                                        Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword)))
                                .WithDefault(
                                    EqualsValueClause(
                                        LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
                                            Literal(1)))),
                                Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                                Parameter(
                                    Identifier("c"))
                                .WithType(
                                    PredefinedType(
                                        Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)))
                                .WithDefault(
                                    EqualsValueClause(
                                        LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                            Literal("foo")))),
                                Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                                Parameter(
                                    Identifier("e"))
                                .WithType(
                                    IdentifierName("SomeType"))
                                .WithDefault(
                                    EqualsValueClause(
                                        LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.DefaultLiteralExpression,
                                            Token(SyntaxKind.DefaultKeyword)))),
                                Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                                Parameter(
                                    Identifier("f"))
                                .WithType(
                                    IdentifierName("SomeType"))
                                .WithDefault(
                                    EqualsValueClause(
                                        LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.NullLiteralExpression)))})))
                .WithSemicolonToken(
                    Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))))))
.NormalizeWhitespace()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, but I arrived to this solutions:
`ResolveLiteralExpression` handles the downcasting of `parameter.DefaultValue`.

```
    private ParameterListSyntax GenerateParameterListSyntax(MethodInfo info)
    {
        var parameters = info.GetParameters();
        var parameterList = new List<ParameterSyntax>();
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            var parameterSyntax = SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(parameter.Name))
                .WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(TypeNameOrAlias(parameter.ParameterType)));

            if (parameter.IsOptional)
                parameterSyntax = parameterSyntax.WithDefault(SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(ResolveLiteralExpression(parameter.DefaultValue)));
            parameterSyntax = parameterSyntax.WithModifiers(GetModifiers(parameter));

            parameterList.Add(parameterSyntax);
        }

        return SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(parameterList));
    }

    private SyntaxTokenList GetModifiers(ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        var tokens = new List<SyntaxToken>();
        if (parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef) tokens.Add(SyntaxFactory.Token(parameter.IsOut ? SyntaxKind.OutKeyword : SyntaxKind.RefKeyword));
        return SyntaxFactory.TokenList(tokens);
    }

    private LiteralExpressionSyntax ResolveLiteralExpression(object parameterDefaultValue)
    {
        switch(parameterDefaultValue)
        {
            case sbyte n: return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case byte n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case short n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case ushort n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case int n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case uint n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case long n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case ulong n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case float n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case double n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            case decimal n: return  SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(n));
            
            case string s: return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(s));
            case char c: return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.CharacterLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(c));
            case bool b: return b 
                ? SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression) 
                : SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.FalseLiteralExpression);

            case null: return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NullLiteralExpression);
            default: return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.DefaultLiteralExpression);
        }
    }
```